# Mysql- how do I move a view to a table (not a view) in another database?

Tags: mysql

I have the following view

```
`USE test;
CREATE 
VIEW vLibro AS 
SELECT
libros.id_libro,
libros.nombre_libro,
tipos.tipo,
categoria.categoria
FROM
categoria
INNER JOIN libros ON categoria.id = libros.id_categoria
INNER JOIN tipos ON tipos.id = libros.id_tipo ;`
```

how can I move this view to a new table in another database, considering that the 2 databases are inside the same host (localhost),

it's possible?

Comment: only the view?   .. and the table involved  remain in the actual database ?  and what mean "move a view to a table"???

Comment: I want to move or copy the same data columns from the view (database 1) to the new table in another database (database 2)

Comment: then you want copy all the table involved  by vew to another database  and after create the new view  for the new table location